# Comparison of bayesian multinomial logistic regression models

Tags: r, logistic, bayesian

my independent variable has 3 categories, and I have 7 independent variables. I am trying to build several Bayesian multinomial logistic regression models but I couldn't find any package for this in R. Are there any packages to handle this?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you want to fit a model in Bayesian framework, it might be better to write up the model yourself.

Comment: Yes i will write up bayesian models myself but i want to compare them using BF, DIC or etc.

Comment: When you fit model e.g., in OpenBUGS (via R), you will obtain DIC.

Comment: As I know openbugs package is using gibbs sampling. Have you any idea for metropolis algorithm?  Thank you so much for your advice.